# How to copy pose onto different legs of spider?

Tags: animation, pose-mode

Following the [animators survival kit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GtHzpX0FCFY) I animated a single spider leg and I want to avoid having to animate every single leg again. I know can paste an inverted pose with crtl shift v  onto a bones symmetric counter part, but is there a way I can copy the pose onto bone of same side.
From bone 1 to bone 2
[image]

Comment: in the Dope Sheet, enalbe the Only Show Selected option, select the leg you've already animated, copy the keyframes, select another leg, create one keyframe, paste the keyframes previously copied, it should work.

Comment: @moonboots that worked. Thank you. Write your comment as a question so I may submit it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Pose* mode select all the bones of the leg you've already animated. In the *Dope Sheet* enable the *Only Show Selected* option and copy the keyframes. Select all the bones of another leg, create one keyframe (I don't know why it's necessary though) and in the *Dope Sheet* paste the keyframes previously copied. As the *000* location of a bone depends on its location set in *Edit* mode and not on its location in the global space, the second bone won't jump to the first bone location, it will just copy the animation but stays at its current location.